# Dockerで作成したコンテナの保存先ディレクトリについて

Tags: wordpress, docker

Wordpressを立ち上げる環境としてDockerを初めてしようしてみました。
私が参考にしたブログを添付しておきます
→https://webnaut.jp/technology/20170118-1828/

本題のDockerで作った”コンテナ”なのですが、テーマを新しく入れたくてディレクトリを探してみたのですがないと、とりあえずGoogle先生で調べてみた結果

```
/var/lib/docker
```

上記のディレクトリにあると書いてあったのでローカルの中をあさってみたのですが

```
postfix
```

というファイルがしかありませんでした。
これが現状です。

Dockerのコンテナが保存されているディレクトリをしっている方がいたら教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker は仮想実行環境(コンテナ)を立ち上げ、その中でプログラムを実行します。なので、 docker を実行するパソコン(ホスト)のファイルシステムを探しても、何もでてきません。

変更するべきはコンテナの中のファイルシステムです。

```
docker exec -it コンテナ名 bash
```

でコンテナの中に CUI で入れるので、その中から操作を行います。